# How to get request body without content-length?

Tags: php, apache, http-headers

Is there any way to retrieve a request body when a content-length header is not included in the request?

for example, I have this in /var/www/test.php:

```
print_r(apache_request_headers());
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
var_dump($data);
```

And run this command:

```
curl -X POST -d test --header 'Content-Length: ' localhost/test.php
```

I see that there is no content-length header, and $data is empty. If I specify, for instance, a content-length of '3', I get an output for $data of 'tes'.

Is there any way to make php retrieve the request body, irrespective of the content-length header?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to retrieve a request body when a content-length
>   header is not included in the request?

Yes. But you *are* including it in the request.

`curl -d test localhost/test.php` should return:

```
Array
(
    [User-Agent] => curl/7.xx.x
    [Host] => localhost
    [Accept] => */*
    [Content-Length] => 4
    [Content-Type] => application/x-www-form-urlencoded
)

string(4) "test"
```

You can just omit sending the header.

Comment: I am specifying the header in the curl command to simulate a missing header. I WANT it to not include the content-length header, because I have another (large, complicated) program that I can't easily test with which does this.

Comment: So you should edit your question as such. What you want is the behaviour when the content-length header VALUE is absent.